# Next steps in web app(clueless what's next)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My web application consists of users that sign-up/sign-in and of a form where they can submit three values:

Name of project:
Description of project:
Plan for project:

I have a feeling I should generate a controller Project? Is this correct? Or should I use a form?

Ideally I want to later add functionality and a projects page where users can browse projects and add comments to them but that is further down the line.

I am pretty new to rails so any guidance on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks!

Mods please don't ban me for my newb question, I am just trying to learn!

Comment: Have you added a logout functionality?

Comment: Start from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Definitely start at `guides`.  This isn't a real question it's just pretty broad.  If you're new to Rails, go through the guides.  They'll get your on your way to your first app much faster than asking generic questions on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Sign-out functionality has been added. I am tired of all the tutorials online that make you build twitter or a blog. I've done them. I am trying to make something custom. Learn by doing, just following rails guides / tutorials is not helping all that much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is really hard to learn. If you don't want to read a guide anymore then you can check out Rails apps on Github or watch Rails4Zombies.

Yes, you need a route and controller and model and migration and view (several views, each with forms) for this. But the reason why we are telling you to read a guide is because that is nearly the first thing that you have to do as a Rails developer, the "create read update delete", which in your case is to create, read, update, and delete projects.

Actually if you think about it you are sort of making a Twitter thing. Just replace the "tweet" with project and add other fields to it.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I went ahead and kept working on it. I made a controller a route a model a form partial(so i don't repeat myself) and migrated it in my database. Now moving on to next phase.

Comment: Just keep on coding. BTW this is a good resource for me, it might help you too. There is a lot of things that blew my mind in this link: https://learn.thoughtbot.com/trails